# How to increase the forecasting horizon in a weighted moving average?

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I'm having problems on how to "extend" the wma formula so I can see how the following patterns are gonna look like.

```
def wma(arr, period):
kernel = np.arange(period, 0, -1)
kernel = np.concatenate([np.zeros(period - 1), kernel / kernel.sum()])
return np.convolve(arr, kernel, 'same')

df_muestra['wma'] = wma(df_muestra["AT"], 3)

y_1 = df_muestra["AT"]
y_2 = df_muestra['wma']
```

This is how it looks like:

[WMA results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fimAS.png)